Is there a way to write a Python script that can create environment secrets in a Github Actions repository?
I have many Github Actions repositories that need to be updated with environment secrets and repository secrets. I can use the following code with the PyGithub python library to create the repository secrets easily
repositories = ['repo1', 'repo2']

repository_secrets = {
    'secret1': "test1",
    'secret2': test2,
}

for repo_name in repositories:
        repo = g.get_repo(repo_name)

        existing_repo_secrets = repo.get_secrets()

        for secret_name, secret_value in repository_secrets.items():
            if any(secret.name == secret_name for secret in existing_repo_secrets):
                repo.delete_secret(secret_name)
            repo.create_secret(secret_name, secret_value)
            print(f"Updated repository secret '{secret_name}' in {repo_name}.")

        existing_env_secrets = {secret.name: secret for secret in repo.get_secrets()}

However, when we try to create environment secrets it is much more difficult. PyGithub appears to not have a way to create a new environment with secrets underneath it (at least to my understanding). This lead me down a rabbit hole of trying to combine the requests library and cryptography library to create the secrets and at this point I would rather just create all these secrets manually.
Is there a way to create an environment and secrets within that environment through a python script? Here is a screenshot of the interface for what I am trying to do in Github


There's a REST API endpoint for it, but it requires to encrypt the secret first.
